# Declare variable for SELECT statement in Postgres function

Tags: postgresql, functions, postgresql-8.4

I have modified my function, but I have problems with declaring variables. I use Postgres 8.4.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION requestcounterid(_mindate timestamptz, _maxdate timestamptz) 
  RETURNS TABLE (kategorien text, requestcounter int) AS
$func$  
DECLARE
_minid bigint;
_maxid bigint;

BEGIN 

SELECT id  INTO _minid from tablename
where starttime >= $1 ORDER BY starttime ASC LIMIT 1; 
SELECT id  INTO _maxid from tablename
where starttime < $2 ORDER BY starttime DESC LIMIT 1; 

SELECT CASE WHEN duration <= 10000000 THEN '00-01 sec'::text
            WHEN duration <= 40000000 THEN '01-04 sec'
            WHEN duration <= 100000000 THEN '04-10 sec' 
            WHEN duration <= 300000000 THEN '10-30 sec' 
            WHEN duration <= 600000000 THEN '30-60 sec' 
            ELSE 'more than 60 sec' END  
     , count(*)::int                     
FROM   tablename
WHERE  id >= _minid and id <= _maxid
GROUP  BY 1                              
ORDER  BY 1; 

END; 
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Error:

> ```
> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
> HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "requestcounterid" line 12 at SQL statement
> ```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the `SELECT` with the `CASE` expression is something you want to return in the output table, just add `RETURN QUERY` before it:

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT CASE ...
```

**Note:** 8.4 is very old now.  Even 9.0 is out of support by now - consider upgrading to a recent major version soon.  The old ones usually don't get any security (and other) fixes anymore.

Comment: @Version: i know - thats the plan. but we need 8.4 because of an application.

Comment: @liquid in my experience, moving from 8.4 to anything (up until 9.4, IIRC) is quite seamless.

Answer (score 2):

I think we discussed the use of `RETURN QUERY` for plpgsql functions at your previous related question on SO:

- [Create function with SELECT CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35848977/939860)

Again, it would be more efficient to use a simple SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION requestcounterid(_mindate timestamptz, _maxdate timestamptz) 
  RETURNS TABLE (kategorien text, requestcounter int) AS
$func$
   SELECT CASE WHEN duration <=  10000000 THEN '00-01 sec'::text
               WHEN duration <=  40000000 THEN '01-04 sec'
               WHEN duration <= 100000000 THEN '04-10 sec'
               WHEN duration <= 300000000 THEN '10-30 sec'
               WHEN duration <= 600000000 THEN '30-60 sec'
               ELSE 'more than 60 sec' END
        , count(*)::int  
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  id >= (SELECT id FROM tbl
                 WHERE starttime >= $1 ORDER BY starttime ASC LIMIT 1)
   AND    id <= (SELECT id FROM tbl
                 WHERE starttime <  $2 ORDER BY starttime DESC LIMIT 1)
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY 1;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Multiple separate queries and assignments are more expensive.